# Iterate over IOString buffer in python

Tags: python, io, buffer

I have a IOString buffer in python and what I want is iterate it and for each iteration reading a number set of bytes, for example, first iteration going from 0 to 65536, second 65537 to 131072 and go on... I don't know how to do that, I'm using method `read`but just read one byte of the position I'm passing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give an argument to `StringIO.read()` which is the number of bytes to read.

```
myStringIO.seek(0)
first = myStringIO.read(65536)
second = myStringIO.read(65536)
```